# How to Read content of different file(.txt, .pdf, .docx) Using ReactFileReader component in react js

Tags: reactjs, file-read

I want to read the content of  uploaded file(with different file extension, may be .txt, .docx, .pdf) in react js. My code is below. Now i am using ReactFileReader component. In my coding, it can read just content of txt file. It can't read content of pdf, docx. How to solve it. Please help me. Thank You.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';
    
class DisplayController extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            file : ""
        }
    }
    
    handleFiles = files => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = function () {
            alert("Read Data : " + reader.result)
        }
        
        reader.readAsText(files[0])
    }
 
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="files">
                    <ReactFileReader fileTypes={['.pdf','.txt','.docx']} handleFiles={this.handleFiles}>
                        <button className='btn'>Upload</button>
                    </ReactFileReader>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
    
export default DisplayController;
```

Comment: Don't read the files as text, read them as data. Why do you want to read them at all? Just add the blob to form data.

Answer (score 2):

It's very complicated, but not impossible, to read the contents of a docx file: That file is a .zip file that contains a lot of other files, which in return contain XML markup describing the file contents.
But this is something that usually is not done in a browser as none of the tools required for that are shipped by default with browsers. You would probably need dozens of additional libraries to deal with that.
Something like that should probably be done on a server.

It is however almost completely impossible to read the contents of a pdf. A pdf can take *many* forms and in the worst case it has not strings characters embedded, but glyphs or little images of characters, along with coordinates for every single character.
Unless you know the exact tool that pdf was created and knew exactly how the file for that would look internally, it is not feasible to parse that into text.
You could investigate to use a component to display the pdf to your user instead, if that matches your use case somethow. That should be possible.

Comment: First of all, reading and displaying PDF in javascript is easy. There is a library for that. However, if I understand correctly what does `react-file-reader` do, then the contents of the file are completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Sulthan rendering for a human to read, yes. But from OPs example, they want to extract text. And that is non-trivial in every language due to the complex file format. There is no guarantee that characters in a pdf are stored in order. They could be stored bottom-to-top, right-to-left or in a spiral from the center of the page. Easier for a human eye, almost impossible to parse. Ever tried copy&pasting a badly formatted pdf?
Oftentimes you even need OCR for that, if that even works.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question but maybe you are right. The question is not clear

Comment: @phry it is very possible to read pdf file content in js using pdfjs-dist package. However, it doesn't work with react and idk why. But reading pdf content is not a problem in js, there are pckages/libaries easily available for that

Comment: @PraiseHart that package will display the contents but not make the contents available as a string. The question was not worded to "display the contents to the user", but to "read" them and the code sample explicitly tried to access a `readAsText` method, so I'm still assuming OP wants a string.